# Calculate NDos-size of given integer

Tags: code-golf, number

## Objective

Given a nonnegative integer, calculate its **NDos-size** as defined below, and output it.

## NDos' numeral system

The concept of NDos-size comes from the numeral system I made. It represents every nonnegative integer by a nested list, as follows:

- With the binary expansion of given nonnegative integer, each entry of the corresponding NDos-numeral stands for each set bit (`1`). The order of the entries is LSB-first.
- The content of each entry is, recursively, the NDos-numeral of the number of the trailing `0`s of the `1` that the entry stands for, counted till the end or another `1`.

For illustrative purposes, here are representations of few integers in NDos' numeral system:

```
Integer = Binary = Intermediate representation = NDos-numeral

0 = []
1 = 1 = [0] = [[]]
2 = 10 = [1] = [[[]]]
3 = 11 = [0, 0] = [[], []]
4 = 100 = [2] = [[[[]]]]
5 = 101 = [0, 1] = [[], [[]]]
6 = 110 = [1, 0] = [[[]], []]
7 = 111 = [0, 0, 0] = [[], [], []]
8 = 1000 = [3] = [[[], []]]
9 = 1001 = [0, 2] = [[], [[[]]]]
```

The **NDos-size** of the given integer is the number of pairs of square brackets of the corresponding NDos-numeral. That gives the NDos-size of few integers as:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 4
6 -> 4
7 -> 4
8 -> 4
9 -> 5
```

Note that this sequence is not monotone. `18 -> 6` and `24 -> 5` are one counterexample.

## I/O format

Flexible. Standard loopholes apply.

Be careful not to abuse [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/89459) loophole. For example, you cannot just input an NDos-numeral as a string and count its left brackets.

Comment: why is intermediate representation of 3 is [0,0] and not  [1,0]?

Comment: @JayantChoudhary Because its binary expansion has no `0`s.

Comment: This is [A358372](https://oeis.org/A358372) offset by one.

Comment: Could you show more testcases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Bṣ1Ẉß€Ḋ¡S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//QuG5ozHhuojDn@KCrOG4isKhU/874oCcIC0@IOKAnTvDhwrFu8OH4oKsWf//OTk)

A monadic link that takes and returns an integer. Written independently of @[CommandMaster’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265811/42248) but uses effectively the same method.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte!

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks. I’d been trying to find something that worked with `¡` but hadn’t quite got there.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
λNb1¡€g₅O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3G6/JMNDCx81rUl/1NTq//8/AA) ([or more nicely formatted](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3G6/JMNDCx81rUl/1NTq/7@2zM9eSUHXTkHJvlLnPwA))

### Explanation

Recursively generates the sequence of NDos-sizes for all numbers.

Note that if in the encoding we split by `1`s and count the size of each part, we'll get the same intermediate representation except an additional `0`. But that additional `0` is good, because it accounts for the `+1` we need for the outer pair of brackets.

```
λ        # recursive environment, with base case a(0)=1
 N        # push the current index
 b        # convert it to binary
 1¡       # split on ones
 €g       # push the size of each part
 ₅        # recursively calculate a(i) for each part size
 O        # and sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or f(d:=len(bin(n&-n))-3)+f(n>>d+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5BDsIgEEX3nGJWlklLIrWLhljuAqEoSZ02BBeexU03eidvI4kQVzN5_7_MPN_bI11X2vfXPXkxfqSfFnOzzgApOss1gudOTctM3AbidBCEKE7Yek5au1ZiEa3P3QCBIBq6zFweUTGALQZKPHTQCN10kLWAyNgPY5lyrLnPO1bcD3_cD1gu1Ve_)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>65</s> 57 bytes

-8 thanks to @bsoelch

```python
f=lambda x:sum(map(f,map(len,f"{x:b}".split('1')[1:])))+1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LdNscxJzk1ISFSqsiktzNXITCzTSdEBkTmqeTppSdYVVUq2SXnFBTmaJhrqhuma0oVWspqamtiHUAM20_CKFTIXMPIWixLz0VA1DA00rLs6Cosy8Eo1MHQV1XTt1HYU0jUxNTYgGmM0A)

Recursively calculates the NDos-size.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LdNscxJzk1ISFSqsiktzNXITCzTSdEBkTmqeTppSdYVVUq2SXnFBTmaJhrqhuma0oVWspqamtiHUAM20_CKFTIXMPIWixLz0VA1DA00rLs6Cosy8Eo1MHQV1XTt1HYU0jUxNTYgGmM0A)

Comment: You can save a byte by using `bin(x)` instead of `f"{x:b}"`. The `[1:]` will remove the 0b prefix as well

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 37 bytes

```
.+
1$&$*0
{`0?1
#
0
1
}+`(1+)\1
$+0
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcs7DsIwFEXB/mwjJgpYit59tvOpKLOJFKagoKFAdIi1m9CONK/7@/G8tdOw1TZGFPpwMT7VrqLDEN9YB8XzLkI0utb@6CQyhYmZhRUdKOQooYwKmtCMFrTihh/H8YRnvPwA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
1$&$*0
```

Start with the binary representation of `2ⁿ`.

```
0?1
#
```

Keep a running total of the number of `1` bits. The `0?` is part of the unary to binary conversion below. (See the Retina tutorial.)

```
0
1
+`(1+)\1
$+0
```

Convert the `0`s from unary to binary.

```
{`
}`
```

Repeat until there are no more bits to process.

```
#
```

Output the total number of `1` bits generated.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,i)=>x?f(x>>1,~x%2*~i)+x%2*f(i):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLDkAwEADQq8xGMqMlPju0ziKojIiREunK1Stdvc3bp3e6Z8/XU5yyrDE6g0EzGRtGh8HaWn8ha/KPSSUdMnV1dOIBGQxUPTAM0CaVIpjlvOVYy0M2ZA2pUx9/)

-1 byte as suggested by l4m2

Comment: https://tio.run/##FcpLDkAwEADQq8xGMqMlPju0ziKojIiREunK1Stdvc3bp3e6Z8/XU5yyrDE6g0EzGRtGh8HaWn8ha/KPSSUdMnV1dOIBGQxUPTAM0CaVIpjlvOVYy0M2ZA2pUx9/

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0:n<1or n%2*f(a)+f(n//2,~n%2*-~a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY39dJscxJzk1ISFfJ0Em0NrPJsDPOLFPJUjbTSNBI1tdM08vT1jXTqQAK6dYmaUF1JaUBFmQqZeQpFiXnpqRqGBppWXAoKBUWZeSUamToK6rp26joKQN2ZmppcXBBhTShtaAGTTwOyNWHCRiYIYSMTTahNMHcCAA)

Essentially a port of @tsh's JS. But also fairly similar to @ovs's Python.

Comment: You can save one byte `//` -> `/` by switching to Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 107 bytes:

```
lambda x:f(bin(x)[2:])
f=lambda x,c=0:x in['','0']or(f(bin(c)[2:])+f(x[:-1])if'1'==x[-1]else f(x[:-1],c+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc6xbsMgEAbguTzFyQuc4lTGTtIUiY4Z@wKOB9sFFcnBFjDQp3dByNN33P3AbX/hd7XdfXP7Qz73ZXxNPyNEodlkLIvYt2JAouUxqGfZiAjG9pTWtKHD6ljJziV70iz24swHNJpyKmXs00EtXsExqecTR9w9SKiqqoHzF3DCMy1pMx3pCpfMhVwLt8JH4V74zFzTO0SvDkzaDLRZgnLse7WqBv/ut8UERp@WIgryNtYwpZ/N0c/3Kaa@98oFeDBjAxsRQaZQKieE/R8)

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using `f"{c:b}"` instead of `f(bin(c)[2:]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
≔×0ＮθＷ№θ0≔⪫Ｅ⪪θ1∧κ⍘Ｌκ²1θＩ⊕Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwEEX3nqJhNU1qosQdK2SFUWOCF6gwgYYyQDvo8WsJun7v/V932tWjtiHk3puW4GkG9JAcEiVKmha@L8MLHUipxCyz3aczFgUU40IMsxJRlFL82stoCG56gmqyZsPHJIY5NdArcdYeK3aGWrgitdxBH2Eq1@1NXB8eUWAotGcoqXY4IDE2/2KOtsxCSE9h/7Zf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔×0Ｎθ
```

Start with `n` `0`s.

```
Ｗ№θ0
```

Repeat until no more `0`s are left.

```
≔⪫Ｅ⪪θ1∧κ⍘Ｌκ²1θ
```

Convert each run of `0`s to binary.

```
Ｉ⊕Ｌθ
```

Output the final number of `1`s plus one for the containing list.

24 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
⊞υ×0ＮＷ⌈υ≔ΣＥυ⪪∧κ⍘Ｌκ²1υＩＬυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU6xCsIwFNz9ipDpBVLQ4iA4VSfBSqFu4pDW2IS2sTR56n84uhRR9Jf8G1PU5Y47jru7vnIl2vwgqq57oNsHk_clQasAOVnrWlqgQ8rJwjToVlhnsgXG2HRwUrqSBGJx1jXWgIyRyFpdGEi9jEXTF6RNpR1EZgclJzNhZepabQpYSlM4BSXjJGQe6Ij2hL438QEHc2HdP4X93t1muf0dfG5ocKzo9haOv8YH) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ×0Ｎ
```

Start with `n` `0`s.

```
Ｗ⌈υ
```

Repeat until no more `0`s are left.

```
≔ΣＥυ⪪∧κ⍘Ｌκ²1υ
```

Convert each string of `0`s to binary and split it on `1`s.

```
ＩＬυ
```

Output the final length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```
a?fMS#_MTBa^1o
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbrEu3TfIOV431DnBLjDPMhglC5JdFGJrFQNgA)

#### Explanation

A full program that calculates the NDos size recursively. Identical approach to [Command Master's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265811/16766), but discovered independently.

```lisp
a?fMS#_MTBa^1o
a?             ; Is the argument nonzero?
               ; If so (recursive case):
        TBa    ;  Convert it to binary
           ^1  ;  Split on 1s
     #_M       ;  Take the length of each element
  fMS          ;  Map a recursive call to each and sum the results
               ; Otherwise, the argument is 0 (base case):
             o ;  Return 1
```

Splitting the binary representation on 1s treats it as if there's an extra, empty run of 0s at the beginning. This works out perfectly, since it translates to an extra +1 to the final value, which matches the +1 needed to account for the outer pair of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ò¢ôÍÅx@ßXÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0qL0zcV4QN9Yyg&input=MjUgLW1S)

-2 bytes thanks to two really clever tricks pointed out by Shaggy.

This uses roughly the same method as Command Master’s Python answer.

```
Ò¢ôÍÅx@ßXÊ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Ò            ‎⁡Add 1 to:
 ¢           ‎⁢The input, converted to binary,
  ôÍ         ‎⁣split on elements which are true when inverted.
    Å        ‎⁤Slice this list from index 1 to the end.
     x@      ‎⁢⁡Sum after mapping each X to
       ß     ‎⁢⁢  the result of recursing with
        XÊ   ‎⁢⁣  the length of X as the input.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [10 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=0qL0zcV4QN9Yyg&input=MjUgLW1S)

Comment: @Shaggy Wow, that `Ò` for `-~` is pretty obscure and I definitely never would've found `ôÍ`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,k=0{n<1?1:n%2*f[k]+f[n/2,~n%-2*~k]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYpLDoIwGIT3PQULkZbH30dcqdWDIAs0NphqQ0SSKpSrV2jiwpnNfDPz7M9v75UsDibXkg1mz498a2KRqlJXmSoNFflk4kKkk66cbyPMAMSGwKNu8VoRhLRcKs6CQj@MdlSlrRxcmt7oBa37DRbudfeC7va5ujRJUBvpALs5yIligIyc@L/pPK54uPkv)

#### Bonus stage:

The solution is nothing particularly original, (as it often happens), but I went a little deeper down the rabbit hole and found an interesting pattern and put that in the test cases.

I can't prove anything with so little data, but if I perform a run-length encoding of the sequence, then discard the values and keep only the length, the longest run is always  <s>7</s> 9, and the sequence starts from the beginning after **4423** "chunks". Going a little further, the sequence seems to be always the same, and always repeating every 4423 chunks, or  <s>32080</s> **16384** numbers.

I don't think that this pattern will repeat forever, I guess that some arbitrary large n multiplied by 16384 will break the sequence.